# Traefik 2 Ingress Route send params on request

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, load-balancing, haproxy, traefik

I have successfully deployed and configured Collabora CODE on kubernetes using [this helm chart](https://github.com/CollaboraOnline/online/tree/master/kubernetes/helm#collabora-online-for-kubernetes)

Everythings works perfect until adding more than 1 replicas, since editing same document must be served by the same pod. ([Ref](https://sdk.collaboraonline.com/docs/installation/Kubernetes.html#collabora-online-for-kubernetes))

They solved this using [HA Proxy Ingress Controller](https://github.com/CollaboraOnline/online/blob/b55f07a91ee6af8096aa85f4bf05d8b5f1b9f55b/kubernetes/helm/README.md?plain=1#L15-L32) and [Nginx Load Balancer](https://sdk.collaboraonline.com/docs/installation/Proxy_settings.html?highlight=wopisrc#example-with-nginx)

Here is the nginx load balancer example

```
upstream coolwsd {
  zone coolwsd 64k;
  hash $arg_WOPISrc;

  server coolwsd1.private:9980;
  server coolwsd2.private:9980;
}
```

Here is the haproxy ingress example

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    haproxy.org/timeout-tunnel: "3600s"
    haproxy.org/backend-config-snippet: |
      mode http
      balance leastconn
      stick-table type string len 2048 size 1k store conn_cur
      http-request set-var(txn.wopisrcconns) url_param(WOPISrc),table_conn_cur()
      http-request track-sc1 url_param(WOPISrc)
      stick match url_param(WOPISrc) if { var(txn.wopisrcconns) -m int gt 0 }
      stick store-request url_param(WOPISrc)
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
```

Is possible to achieve this using Traefik 2 sending this `WOPISrc` param?

Comment: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/services/#sticky-sessions

Comment: I've tried sticky sessions but they only work in one way, only one user is being served by the same pod, another user continues to be served by another pod and rarely shares the same pod